# asp.net core httpclient ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a POST request using HttpClient but it keeps throwing an ArgumentNullException. 
on this call `var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);`

I've set break points and verified that the values are populated.
Is there something I'm missing that would cause this?

```
public async Task<bool> PostSomeObject()
{
var transaction = new CreateTransactionRequest();

transaction.MerchantAuthentication.Name = "notmyName";
transaction.MerchantAuthentication.TransactionKey = "notMyKey";
transaction.TransactionRequest.TransactionType = "authOnlyTransaction";
transaction.TransactionRequest.Amount = 5;
transaction.TransactionRequest.Payment.CardCode = "999";
transaction.TransactionRequest.Payment.CardNumber = "5424000000000015";
transaction.TransactionRequest.Payment.ExpirationMonth = 12;
transaction.TransactionRequest.Payment.ExpirationYear = 20;

var url = "xml/v1/request.api";
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{

    var sampleClassObjectJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transaction);

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56858/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var content = new StringContent(sampleClassObjectJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    //throws NullException on this call here
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);



    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        return true;
    else
        throw new WebException("An error has occurred while calling PostSomeObject method: " + response.Content);
}
}
```

Based on a comment I've added a try catch for the ArgumentNullException

```
            try { 
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
```

It's not stepping into the catch statement but in the Output from debug it throws the exception.

Here is the controller action that calls my Post method

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> PaymentInformation(Payment paymentInfo)
    {

        var cookie = GetCheckoutCookie();
        //if there isn't a cookie ID something went wrong, redirect to Index
        if (cookie.ID == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        var cookieSession = CheckoutSession.getCheckoutSession(cookie.ID);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var status = await PostSomeObject();
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: notice a difference between base address and the one you posted. comment out the `BaseAddress` and see if it makes a difference using the full url in the variable.

Comment: Also show the full stack trace of the error

Comment: @Nkosi I've added a try catch for the NullException and it's not stepping into it for some reason but in the Output log it's showing the Exception as being thrown.

Comment: Ok these symptoms are starting to look familiar. The Methods that the above code belongs to. I need to see what that it looks like and also how that method is being called.  Looks like some where you are mixing async/await and blocking calls (`.Result` or `.Wait()`) .

Comment: ArgumentNullException should have stacktrace and the name of the parameter that is causing issues. This should point you towards the solution.

Comment: @Nkosi I've added the controller that calls the method.

Comment: You can try to remove the using statement, just in case somewhere unseen the client is being disposed of.